# How to turn off magento error reporting magento/var/report/

Tags: magento

I am using magento. It keeps generating error reports files in magento/var/report folder.

it is not a single log file rather thousands of files are generated daily

Is there any way in magento that I can turn that feature off?

Comment: What version of Magento? I don't think any recent versions have used that directory.

Comment: It sounds like there are major issues if "thousands of files are generated daily". What are the errors? You can stop generation of these files by simple removing write permissions from var/report but I don't think that's a real solution.

Comment: that is true. these files are not big in size. mostly error are because of multiple storefront from one magento directory. there must be a way in magento to turn off these erorr reporting.

Comment: just truncate the errors/report.php file and put there header() with redirect to your main page. You should handle those 'thousands'!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I don't have a 1.4.0.1 install at the moment, but I assume this is all mostly the same)

There's no configuration setting for this.  You'll need to customize code to make this happen (Assuming politics/ability/budget are preventing the obvious solution, which is fixing the errors).

These errors are generated when a piece of Magento code calls

```
Mage::printException($e);
```

This method, ultimately, `require`s in the `report.php` file.

```
public static function printException(Exception $e, $extra = '')
{
    //...snip...
    require_once(self::getBaseDir() . DS . 'errors' . DS . 'report.php');
}
```

and `report.php` contains the following

```
#File: errors/report.php
require_once 'processor.php';

$processor = new Error_Processor();

if (isset($reportData) && is_array($reportData)) {
    $processor->saveReport($reportData);
}

$processor->processReport();
```

It's the call to `saveReport` which saves out the files that are vexing you

```
public function saveReport($reportData)
{
    $this->reportData = $reportData;
    $this->reportId   = abs(intval(microtime(true) * rand(100, 1000)));
    $this->_reportFile = $this->_reportDir . '/' . $this->reportId;    
    //...snip...
    @file_put_contents($this->_reportFile, serialize($reportData));
    //...snip...
}
```

Nowhere in this execution chain (even in the snipped code, I promise)  is there condition code that checks a configuration before writing the files or calling `printException`.  This means the only way to achieve what you want is to modify the files manually.

**How** you do that is up to you, if it were me I'd comment out the `file_put_contents` line.

```
#@file_put_contents($this->_reportFile, serialize($reportData));
```

This is a single line change, but the existing behavior of the store is otherwise maintained.

All that said — the real solution is to fix the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Error reporting is a valuable tool and by disabling it you are removing a very useful resource from your developer toolkit. I would try and fix the errors that are being reported rather than hiding the logs themselves.

That said, you can disable this error reporting in one of two ways. I'd recommend the first, but if you're in a production environment you might not want to display error messages to everyone.

1. Turn on Developer mode. This will put the error message right on the page and files in var/report will not be generated. There are a few ways to do this, here is one:

   ```
   // In index.php, after Magento is loaded but before Mage::run();
   Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
   ```
2. Modify the permissions on var/report so that the web server user (www-data, apache, depending on your setup) does not have write permissions.

   ```
   # If the directory is not owned by www-data this is sufficient, otherwise
   # change go-w to a-w
   $ chmod go-w var/report
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line

require_once MAGENTO_ROOT  . DS .  'errors' . DS . 'report.php';

$x = $y + $z;

After the line

require_once $mageFilename;

In the index.php page, this will force the error to be displayed in report.php

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need to do, go to: `System -> Configuration -> Advanced - > Developer -> Log Settings -> Enabled = 'No'`.

If you are referring to the log tables, you need to add a cron that would clean that up. I could give you more details, let me know if that is the case.

Comment: No, this isn't correct. The log settings do not affect the error reports in var/report

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad. This would disable the logging not the error reports.